# TYPO3: could BE users only see the records they created?

Tags: typo3

Is it possible, with an extension or something else, to make that the BE user could only see certain records-types, only if such records have been created them by themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of records?

If for an example news, or other records from some extension, the easiest way is create separate `sysfolder` for every user so you can use `WEB`>`Access` module to disable/enable visibility. If you want on one page display different records for different users it will be rather difficult without writing own BE module.

If you have just few BEusers - do it manually, otherwise I'd suggest writing the module.

Tip: it looks like `Extbase` allows for easier creating of BE modules than oldschool PI- way (my personal experience).

Comment: ALl kinds of modules. tt_news as well as custom. I guess I have to write a BE module, but not sure where to start. Any hint, please?

Comment: Well it's long way before you, check my tip... maybe it will help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extension made for this purpose:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/maja_becacl

altough its last update its from 2007 so maybe it will not work out of the box. But you can use that as a base for you own solution.